# Setting the Maximum Title Length: Blogspot

Tags: html, blogger, element, blogspot

can i set maximum title length in blogspot index page? 
If the title exceeds the maximum length, the letters or words which do not fit are replaced with "...". And only in index, the original title still the same if you go to the post.

```
            <h4 class='title'><a expr:href='data:post.href' rel='bookmark'><data:post.title/></a></h4>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set title length in index pages by javascript. Paste this code before `</body>`.
You can change the maximum length `30`.

```
<b:if cond='data:blog.pageType == "index"'>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
$(".title").each(function(){
    if($(this).text().length>30)
    {$(this).text($(this).text().substr(0, 30)+'...');}
});    
//]]>
</script>
</b:if>
```